# wso2am publisher UI issue

Tags: wso2-api-manager

After modifying endpoint suspend stat in publisher and edit it again. But we cant see previous modification.
[Attatched screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9AYq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a know issue[1] and fixed in next release. Even configurations are not shown in UI they will be applied in synapse configuration file when you publish the api.

[1].https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-5225